# Is there a "Hello world!" example for radiance?

Tags: radiance

I have been reading about radiance for a few days, but still have not come across what appears to me as a *really* simple example.  Is it possible to run something with a single light source and a single surface?  What would be the simplest example possible?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the simplest possible example, but I have found the tutorials and pointers posted here to be helpful:  http://www.radiance-online.org/learning/tutorials.  In particular, the Scene 0 tutorial probably fits your needs.  The Alex Jacobs tutorial above is also helpful.  these tutorials go through the process of defining materials, objects, sources and views, and combining them all into an octree file for visualization.